# DNS bind9 : can't see cache

Tags: caching, dns, bind

I am using seed Ubuntu 12.04 with two different virtual machines: the first is for a DNS server that runs BIND9 and the second simulate a user/client. My mission is to poison the DNS server cache.

In the user machine i configure the primary DNS address to the address of the DNS server machine.

Well, this is the context of the `named.conf.options` file (location is `/etc/bind/`) :

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    //dnssec-validation auto;
    dnssec-enable no;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    dump-file   "/var/cache/bind/dump.db";
    query-source port 33333;
};
```

In the user I've tried to enter some different addresses with different host names (`google.com` , `cnn.com`, etc..) to see the impact in the cache file.

The problem: no matter what I do, the cache file is remain empty. Ofcourse I use the dump command:

```
sudo rndc dumpdb -cache
```

but still the file `/var/cache/bind/dump.db` is empty.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that your Ubuntu install of bind defaults to using a chroot. The file will have been created relative to the root directory of your chroot environment in which bind is running/configured.

For example, on Redhat style distributions `/var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf` would only refer to `dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";`; However, its full path would be `/var/named/chroot/var/named/data/cache_dump.db`.

Also, regardless of the chroot environment, you may be able to also locate the file using tools such as locate(1) or find(1).